# Chrome Native Messaging Host Access Rights

Tags: google-chrome-extension, npapi, chrome-native-messaging

I am porting my NPAPI based plugin to Native messaging host for Chrome.

I can connect to it successfully and also run the host application.

But the host application (win32 GUI App) uses many win32 API's like CreateFile to update itself and other utilities from server.

The host app is installed in Program Files folder through an installer process (setup.exe). So since the host application runs on current user rights ( I may be wrong on this) the host might not have some rights (like in my case CreateFile) in the program files folder.

Through NPAPI it used to work as the executable i guess runs under System Rights (I may be wrong on this too).

So basically is there any way I can achieve this. I know this might be a security concern Chrome is trying to solve through Native Host, but I need to do this as otherwise some executable will not be updated from server.

Also the native host application requires some more files to be downloaded from server ( which i could not be placed in the installer).

Moreover, the source code to update the executables and download extra utilities is cross platform so I don't to change that, otherwise I might need to rewrite a lot of code.

So any suggestions to get around this situation ?

Is there some way we can get elevated permissions for the native host application through UAC or something. I don't mind if user is prompted for a UAC dialog.

Or are there any other alternative besides Native Messaging ? NaCl won't suffice either I guess.

Note : GetLastError() reutrns ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED during CreateFile.
Regards,
LazyCoder7.

Comment: Why not install your program in `%LOCALAPPDATA%`, as Chrome sometimes does? You don't need special privileges to write there.

Comment: Wont the app data folder deleted/cleaned on rebooot? Will my application persist on that location till Uninstall ?

Comment: no, local app data is not deleted or cleaned on reboot

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and helping me out here. I will try this out now.

Comment: @LazyCoder7 - did this suggestion solve your problem?

Comment: I did something different. I had used Inno setup for creating the installer I set the directory permission for everyone-modify. This did the trick for me.